# C++ If I have an object pointer, are the method variables allocated on the stack or heap?

Tags: c++

I have been searching for about an hour now, but haven't found a clear answer. If I use an object pointer, are the local variables allocated on the stack?

For example:

```
   class SomeClass {
      public:
         int a;
         int some_method() {
            int local_variable = 5;
            return local_variable + a;
         }
   };

   SomeClass *obj_ptr = new SomeClass();
   obj_ptr->a = 5; // I'm aware that this variable is allocated on the heap.

   // Is local_variable allocated on the stack? Is the return value on the stack?
   obj_ptr->some_method();
```

Comment: Most likely, they'll all be in registers in this case.

Comment: just because you use a method or call a method through a pointer it doesn't change the way local variables are treated.

Comment: @Paul You know you can check this yourself on your platform by printing out the address of the local variable during the some_method() call and comparing it to the address of the heap (obj_ptr). Also the return address may be held in the function frame (or stack frame) which would be preallocated on the heap (in your case its an int).

Comment: @Mohammad: That's rather meaningless. In particular, `&local_variable` will most likely force the variable out of a register. So only your attempt to print the address causes it to have an address.

Comment: @MSalters Well, I printed the member variable a and local_variable. a has the same address as obj_ptr while local_variable doesn't. This leads me to think that printing it doesn't "force" it to have an address since it didn't force a to have its own address. However, I guess it could be "forced" in the case that user4815162342 mentions below.

Comment: @Paul: member variables are stored within an object; all the memory was allocated by `new SomeClass`. As it happens, only `SomeClass::a` needed memory (methods don't) so it's located at the begin of `SomeClass`.

Comment: @MSalters Awe, of course. If methods don't require memory, then local variables of methods would never be allocated on the heap without explicitly being told to, correct?

Comment: Well, technically that's all implementation details (trivially, the stack itself may be a big object on the heap). Practically speaking, local variables are never on the heap, and you can't explicitly make them. You can however have a local variable of pointer type which points to an object on the heap.

Comment: Wow, searching for a whole hour. In my day we performed _days_ of research! At least!

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Gee, thanks smart a**. These days, an hour of searching with no results is sufficient to conclude that the answer either isn't out there or is convoluted. It's reasonable to ask a question after that time frame. It's comments like these that make people hesitant to ask questions. If everyone researched every little question for days and days, this site would not exist, nothing would get done, and we'd all learn a lot less! Lastly, I don't know what period you are referring to by "my day", but this is now - an hour of research is equivalent to days of research decades ago

Comment: @Paul: No, it's not even nearly enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a mental model, it is not wrong to imagine that `local_variable` is allocated on some kind of stack, since it has automatic storage and its scope ends with the scope of the function.

A member function ("method") is no different in that regard from any other function. The one implementation difference is that member functions receive the pointer to the current object as a hidden argument accessible inside the function as `this`.

If the question is literally where the variables are allocated during runtime, that will depend on your compiler, platform, and optimization level. The optimizer can transform the code in surprising ways, including eliminating much of it. Many automatic variables will be allocated in registereds, and some will be optimized away completely - for example, in your case the compiler could emit a CPU instruction that increments the integer contents of a known memory address by 5. The constant `5` would only be present in the disassembly (the "text" segment), and not on the stack or the heap.

Comment: I think all this talk of registers is unnecessarily confusing. Optimisations should be transparent to the programmer who is only programming to the model of the C virtual machine. Knowledge of registers might be useful when optimising but that is not what is being asked here.

Comment: @sjdowling I agree, and that sentiment is exactly what prompted me to write this answer. Strictly speaking, the C programming model doesn't really mention a "stack" either (AFAIK), only storage durations. The OP is asking a straightforward question about mapping the C model (where `local_variable` is automatic storage) to a simplified machine model (where `local_variable` is "allocated on the stack") and deserves a straight answer that is within his current learning phase.

Comment: @sjdowling: Yes, that's the entire point. Asking whether a variable will be "on the stack" or "on the heap" is _the wrong question_, and this answer explains why that is.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation will, we hope, put them wherever is most efficient on that particular platform. For the examples you cited, that will likely be in registers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between object pointes and other local variables. In an non-optimizing compiler, usually all local variables will be on the stack. Although the object pointer itself is on the stack, it will point to an arbitrary memory location, most commonly on the heap.

In an optimizing compiler local variables will often be places in registers, but still, the pointer can point to any memory location.